# using the ASP.NET MVC2 without the Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning asp.net MVC, as I have been using the sqlconnection, sqlcommands etc from my initial phases, I would like to initially start learning asp.net MVC without using the entity framework.

Can you give me a link or any idea of using the models to process data without using the entity framework.

Comment: The answers provide a good starting point. But don't forget to abstract away the points of data access. That way if you decide to use EF in the future you swap your ADO.NET implementations out. This will also help with testability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So without entity framework you'll be using [ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

Those classes you mentioned SqlConnection, SqlCommand are part of the ADO.NET framework. The two Microsoft frameworks that build on this are Entity Framework and LinqToSQL.

If you don't want to us either you have to **write you own** models/classes, and then methods to persist those models into your database. (This is essentially what EF does) You won't get any LINQ or designers etc.

Also, ADO.NET does have a way to create strongly typed datasets. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) might help a little.

What you are doing might help you understand whats going on under the covers, but do realize frameworks like Entity-Framework save a lot of time and effort by generating models for you.

Comment: Hi giddy, thanks for your reply. Currently i am having my models with the sqlconnections and datasets etc.. I am returning the datarow objects from the model and getting them in the controller and passing them to the view and displaying data there. But what do i need is to know whether there is any way for me to pass datarow to a view like {return View(model.MovieDetails(id));}. If i send so, how can i receive the datarow in the view and display the data there.

Comment: ok. So depending on what version of asp.net you use, you can **(1)** define your model for the view as the **type** returned by `model.MovieDetails(id)` (Write `@model <typename>` for razor/cshtml or `Inherits="ViewPage<Your type>"`) Then `return View(modle...)` should work.

Comment: **(2)** You can use ViewData or If you are on .net 4 you can use the C#4 dynamic keyword with ViewBag to pass any type from the controller to the view. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx

Comment: @saravanan Also see this.http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/27/asp-net-mvc-3-new-viewmodel-is-dynamic-viewdata.aspx

Comment: @giddy Thanks for the links. I am using .net framework V4.0, VS2010 and MVC 2.0. Currently the ViewData works fine. But let me explore on the other options so that i can create a strongly typed views.

Comment: Yes strongly typed views are better as I mentioned in **(1)**

Comment: I need one another clarification. I have implemented the entire application without using the entity framework and things are working fine. I have used the `Request.Form["firstname"];` kind of syntax to get the form's posted values that i get after i submit. Then i submit those data. However I need a way so that i can pass the entire form values to the updateModel function of the controller so that it gets updated, instead of writing a long list of code for all the individual properties. Kindly suggest me.

Comment: i think that the framework of my application has a bit of confusion.. let me comeback sometime later.

Comment: @saravanan See this http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx